# how to display filesize in KB instead of bytes

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

Very happy with the result of this script however I would like the result to display like:

example:

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----          9-3-2023     19:31         817.6435546875/Kb 200w.gif
```

basically I would like the length to be displayed in Kilobytes instead of bytes (round up by preference)

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.7z, *.rar, *.zip, *.db, *.sql, *.bmp, *.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.odp, *.pps, *.ppt, *.pptx, *.ods, *.xls, *.xlsx, *.doc, *.docx, *.pdf, *.rtf, *.txt
```

I tried a few things but i'm fairly new to powershell and have not been able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) with `Select-Object`, the *expression* you can use is:

```bash
[math]::Round($_.Length / 1kb, 2)
```

Where `2` determines the number of fractional digits in the return value.

The code would look like this:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.7z, *.rar, *.zip, *.db, *.sql, *.bmp, *.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.odp, *.pps, *.ppt, *.pptx, *.ods, *.xls, *.xlsx, *.doc, *.docx, *.pdf, *.rtf, *.txt |
    Select-Object Mode, LastWriteTime, @{N='Length (Kb)'; E={ [math]::Round($_.Length / 1kb, 2) }}, Name
```

Comment: Much appreciated, Feel like I learned something today.